# android app lock required for socket connection?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-wake-lock

my app maintains a socket connection with a server through a Service I coded, but once the phone sleeps (a couple minutes after the screen turns off), I am unable to get the typical response from the sleeping phone. A sound is normally played when the Service receives a network event.

My question is, do I need a wake_lock to be able to have my app function.  If so, for what components is this wake_lock helpful for?  I am curious about the sound and the socket connection.  Will I be able to do this with only a partial wake_lock?

As for the socket connection, will I need an additional wifi lock if it is done under wifi?  The socket connection only consists of small transaction once a while, so is there a way that I can have the socket connection not under wifi (even if the user enabled wifi), so I don't have to wifi lock and waste power? or are socket connection conveniently done only under 3g/4g or can gracefully degenerate from wifi to 3g/4g?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> do I need a wake_lock to be able to have my app function

Generally, yes. *If* your network connection is via mobile data and *if* you have an open socket to a server and *if* that server sends packets to you, that will wake up the phone briefly. However, to do any serious work, you need to then acquire a `WakeLock`. And if any of the italicized *if* statements from above are not true, then you need a `WakeLock` as long as you are trying to maintain this connection.

Hence, please consider switching to C2DM for push notifications.

> Will I be able to do this with only a partial wake_lock?

A partial `WakeLock` should suffice.

> will I need an additional wifi lock if it is done under wifi?

Yes.

> is there a way that I can have the socket connection not under wifi (even if the user enabled wifi), so I don't have to wifi lock and waste power?

Not really. You request the socket connection. You use whatever network is active at the time.

> or are socket connection conveniently done only under 3g/4g or can gracefully degenerate from wifi to 3g/4g?

Network connectivity gracefully falls back to mobile data if WiFi powers down or otherwise becomes unavailable. However, *socket connnections* do not. If you have a socket connection on WiFi, and WiFi powers down, your socket is closed, and you would need to reopen it on the new network.

Comment: To drain the battery efficiently in the background I'd recommend abusing a WiFiManager.WifiLock.

Comment: what is the advantage of C2DM?

Comment: @RickyPanzer: You don't have to maintain the socket connection -- Android does. You don't even need an always-on server for the other end of the socket connection -- Google supplies one.